# Efficient predictions from pytorch model (transformers library) for NLP tasks with a GPU

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have a huge data set of tweet texts (almost 3 billion tweets). I finetuned a BERT model with an annotated data set for a classification task.

Is there a way to make predictions more efficient and faster? I have access to one GPU only.

At the moment I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

import sys

from transformers import pipeline

judge = pipeline(
task="sentiment-analysis",
model="/trained_disasterlabels",
tokenizer='bert-base-uncased',
device=0)

id_disaster=sys.argv[1]

path="/disaster_data/ids_"+id_disaster+"_text"

open(path+"_labelpred", 'w').close()

n=200
with open(path,"rb") as f:
    batch=[]
    for line in f:
        batch.append(line.decode().rstrip("\n"))
        if len(batch)==n:

            preds=judge(batch)
            preds_labels=[x['label'].replace("LABEL_","") for x in preds]
            preds_probs=[round(x['score'],4) for x in preds]
            
            valsdf=pd.DataFrame({"labels":preds_labels,"probs":preds_probs})
            
            valsdf.to_csv(path+"_labelpred", mode='a', header=False,index=False)
            
            batch=[]

    preds=judge(batch)
    preds_labels=[x['label'].replace("LABEL_","") for x in preds]
    preds_probs=[round(x['score'],4) for x in preds]
    
    valsdf=pd.DataFrame({"labels":preds_labels,"probs":preds_probs})
    
    valsdf.to_csv(path+"_labelpred", mode='a', header=False,index=False)
```

Before I also experimented with the following:

```
model=BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("/trained_disasterlabels")

model.eval()

model.to('cuda')

tokenizer=BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

import torch.nn.functional as F 

path="/disaster_data/ids_"+id_disaster+"_text"

open(path+"_labelpred", 'w').close()

n=100
 
with open(path,"rb") as f:
    batch=[]
    for line in f:
        batch.append(line.decode().rstrip("\n"))
        if len(batch)==n:
           input_ids = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(batch, add_special_tokens=True,return_tensors = 'pt', padding=True, truncation=True)
            
            input_ids.to('cuda')
            
            with torch.no_grad():
                last_hidden_states = model(**input_ids)
            
            temp_cpu = F.softmax(last_hidden_states[0],dim=1).detach().cpu().numpy()    

            valsdf=pd.DataFrame(temp_cpu.tolist(),columns=["prob","labelpred"])
                        
            batch=[]
            
    input_ids = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(batch, add_special_tokens=True,return_tensors = 'pt', padding=True, truncation=True)

    with torch.no_grad():
        last_hidden_states = model(**input_ids)  
        
    temp_cpu = F.softmax(last_hidden_states[0],dim=1).detach().cpu().numpy()
            
    valsdf=pd.DataFrame(temp_cpu.tolist(),columns=["labelpred","prob"])
    
    valsdf.to_csv(path+"_labelpred", mode='a', header=False,index=False)
           
    batch=[]
```

Comment: You can look into [automatic mixed precision (AMP)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html). That will give you some speedup (and also reduce memory usage).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! unfortunately, i only have a Nvidia GTX 1080 Ti, which should prevent me from having an advantage from this, right? (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/865) Another solution that came to my mind would involve downsampling by randomly choosing 10 000 tweets or so from each day in our observation period, maybe I go with something along those lines...

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/znxlwm/pytorch-apex-experiment), yeah, probably AMP will be marginally slower (but will take lesser memory). However, for larger batch sizes, they show FP16 being marginally faster (and with lesser memory). Since you have to do prediction on a lot of inputs, that marginal speedup may help (not sure how much).